# Error in postgres driver in jdbc

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql

I tried to create a driver for postgres using JDBC, but I'm getting an error in the driver manager. How can I fix this code?

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dvdrental2","postgres","vibhug");
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from actor ");

            while(rs.next())  
            {
                int actor_id = rs.getInt("actor_id");
                String  first_name = rs.getString("first_name");
                int last_name  = rs.getInt("last_name");

                System.out.println( "ID = " + actor_id );
                System.out.println( "fNAME = " + first_name );
                System.out.println( "AGE = " + last_name );

                System.out.println();
            }
            con.close();  
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("operation done successfully!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Opened database successfully
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type int : Guiness
operation done successfully!!!
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toInt(PgResultSet.java:2834)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getInt(PgResultSet.java:2060)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getInt(PgResultSet.java:2495)
 at jdbc.main(jdbc.java:19)

Comment: I think something is wrong in while loop!!!

Comment: Are you really saving the age in a column called `last_name`? Seems like it should be a string...

Comment: no that is just a string

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to retrieve the `last_name`, which is most probably a string as an `int`. Fix that, and it should be OK:

```
String last_name  = rs.getString("last_name");
```